# Capistrano throws /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory when performing a deploy:migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rvm, capistrano

I set up Capistrano to make the deploy of my app. I made it in steps, so first I set up the code deployment, so I commented all the roles but `:app`.

I'm using `rvm` and I had some problems with it. The biggest problem was an error that said `/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory`. I solved them using the gem `capistrano/rvm` and requiring it in the `Capfile` and adding the following line to the `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :default_env, { path: "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:$PATH" }
```

Once the code deploying runned correctly I activated de `:db` role in order to perform migrations. I get the same error but I can't find the solution this time.

```
~$ cap production deploy:migrate
    …
    …
 INFO [85d6241d] Running bundle exec rake db:migrate on 10.10.51.10
 DEBUG [85d6241d] Command: cd [PROJECT_SRC]/current 
                  && ( PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:$PATH RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate )
 DEBUG [85d6241d]            /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
 cap aborted!
```

This command runs correctly when I execute it directly in the shell.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked using `gem 'rvm1-capistrano3', require: false`. It seems the best option for my setup (Rails4.0.1, ruby-2.0.0-p247, capistrano3). It didn't require special configuration.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3).

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and this gem helped me:
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano

Comment: It didn't work for my setup, throwed the same error. Maybe it's something related with rails4. Finally I used rvm1-capistrano3. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using rvm, then the issue is usually you'll have to manually install bundler gem on the server.

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried offical capistrano gems? That helped me, maybe your use case is similiar.

Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
...
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
...
```